# C# VSTO -- Detection of unused slide layouts

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, vsto

I am programming a PowerPoint add-in in C# (VSTO).

About my problem, I want to delete all master slides that are not used. I have been programming this function for quite a long time now and I can't get it to work.
I also can't find a solution anywhere.

In the attached picture, you can see what I want to check.

[image: Check picture]

I hope one of you can help me, I thank you in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: A simple google search gave me a least 3 hits including one on stackoverflow.  You want programming help please show us your code (that what is relevant), a description of the problem and describe what you have tried already

Comment: I apologize for the errors in my question.
Yes, I have found the solution to my problem, I have simply rewritten currently shown VB macros for PowerPoint in C#.

https://superuser.com/questions/835809/remove-all-unused-master-slides-in-a-powerpoint-presentation